# StorefrontRenderEvent::class event

Tags: shopware

StorefrontRenderEvent::class event in Shopware 6.2. this event is working only once. then it is not working. I think the event is cached by Shopware.
What I can do?

I want to get the customer id, sales channel context, and need to pass some params to view page. Are there any events available for this without caching?

Answer (score 1):

Shopware uses Full Page Http Cache. You should consider using Ajax for dynamic things